# NSTimer stop when app is hide?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

I just want to know why a NSTimer is stoping when the application is hidden or "Hide other" in an other application ?
how can I remedy this ?

Thanks

Comment: I’ve just tested this in my application and I haven’t been able to reproduce your issue — the timer keeps firing when the application is hidden, as expected. Is there anything particular about your application?

Comment: What method are you calling to add the timer to the run loop?

Comment: it's just an action on a NSButton

Comment: (IBAction)recordCam1:(id)sender {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(recordFile1:)
                                   userInfo:Nil
                                    repeats:YES];
    
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your timer is getting garbage collected or otherwise freed perhaps by the autorelease pool, and hence does not fire anymore.

Try doing this:

```
- (IBAction)recordCam1:(id)sender {
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(recordFile1:) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
    [myTimer retain];
}
```

where myTimer is an instance variable in your class. See if that produces a different behaviour. If so, then you know the problem is to do with memory management.

Comment: A scheduled timer will be retained by the run loop in manual-retain/release-land; I don't know how it goes under GC or ARC. Under GC, the `retain` message does nothing; simply storing the pointer in an instance variable (that isn't marked as `__weak`) is a strong reference that will keep it alive.